# Jquery BeforeShowDay pick even or odd

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

i was trying something but i cant figure out problem. i have calendar. If i choose even month only even dates should be pickable and if i choose odd month only odd dates should be pickable. but my problem when i choose odd month it shows all dates and when i choose even month it doesn't show any date.
http://jsfiddle.net/66688hft/1/

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",
           beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    if(month%2==1)
    return [day % 2 == 1];

  else
    return [day % 2 == 0];

}

    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `day` inside your `if`/`else` means quite what you think it does. Can you replicate this behaviour with a demo (either a Stack Snippet, click the button with pencil, next to the image icon, in the editor for the question after clicking '[edit]') or a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David is correct, you aren't getting the day correctly. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
          var day = date.getDate(),
              month = date.getMonth()+1;
          return [day % 2 == month % 2, ''];
      }
  });
}
```